# What to use? Digital signature?

Tags: cryptography, authorization, digital-signature, identification

Sorry I couldn't find the best heading for this question. Following is my requirement.

I a working on a project which deals which large amount of money transactions to different account. The system automatically transfers money to accounts of A,B, C etc etc,, But before this is done Some one from A,B or C should approve(electronically) the amount to be transferred.

What do you think is the best way of doing it? I want the system to send a file (PDF of something) which is digitally signed (?) and the authorised person from A,B and C should check and confirm that the amount is correct.

Since the amount is high I must make sure the file sent out by the system is not tampered and at the same time I also want to make sure the file (reply) sent by A,B or C is also not tampered . What is the best way to achieve it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Digital Signatures is what you are looking for. Adobe PDF (since you mentioned pdf) allows you to sign the pdf in the free Adobe Reader version and verification is also done automatically, as soon as you open the pdf document.

The difference between DigSig and (H)MACs as posted by Noldorin is, that MACs use symmetric encryption, where you require a secure channel to exchange the key, whereas in a [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) environment that secure channel is not required.

It depends how you want to distribute your keys.

Comment: Thanks.. can this verification (reply message) be done programatically using .net?

Comment: I haven't used .net for verification yet, but when you google 'pdf signature verification c#' - you find some promising solutions.

Comment: Ah, that's a good clarification. DSA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm), which is a popular algorithm for digital signatures, is fully implemented in the standard .NET framework (System.Cryptography namespace), so it should be easy enough to use with the appropiate MSN docs.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into [MACs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Integrity_Code) (Message Authentication Codes). There are a number of libraries out there for various languages that implement common algorithms such as [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

EDIT: See also DSA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm), which is a popular algorithm for digital signatures, and is fully implemented in the standard .NET framework (System.Cryptography namespace).

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction would be Digital Signatures - but they have a fatal flaw: they are digital data that could be compromised by a careless user.

If that is a concern you can go for the process that South African banks use, a one-time password. This password is transferred to them via a means that is not involved in the transaction (in South Africa this is by SMS, which I strongly recommend). We first type in a username and password, and then get the OTP via SMS which we then need to type in for any transactions that lead to money leaving our accounts.

Strong forms of security (in increasing effectiveness) include (I am no expert, but I do know a few):

- Knowledge (A password)
- Possession (A cell-phone SIM card that can receive SMSes, or a USB thumbdrive with a certificate)
- Location (A computer with a hardware-based certificate management system, CellID)
- Time (OTP expires, transaction must occur at specific time)
- Identity (A fingerprint reader - effectively a password - but insanely long)
- Uniqueness (A fibre-optic cable encoded in the polarization of the photons)

From what I know if you have any three of those you can be comfortable with your security. Adding more increases security exponentially, but also increases the inconvenience factor. The banks use Knowledge, Possession and Time in South Africa - and phishing really doesn't work against South African banks.

Hope this helped you out a little.

Comment: A fingerprint is nothing like a password. Passwords are secret, biometrics are not. A fingerprint is analogous to a user name, and should be used for authentication only in that role.

Comment: A fingerprint can be used in a SRP exchange @erickson.

Answer (score 0):

To digitally sign a file, you can use any of Microsoft's partners. Arx for example provide you with a tool called CoSign which you can use for free (or at least their trial version). This will allow you to add [electronic signatures](http://www.arx.com) to most available formats (word, pdf, xml etc').